# TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined when loading script in React Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am currently writing test coverage for a component in React that will inject a script tag into the HTML if a prop `newUser` is true. When I'm running the test and I am passing the prop as true, it is failing to append the script tag to the document body and therefore it can't check the script src. My component is

```
class AddScript extends Component {

  render() {
    const {
      newUser,
      async,
    } = this.props;

    const asyncAttribute = async ? true : undefined;

    if (newUser) {
      return 
      <script src="http://www.website.com" async={asyncAttribute}>
      </script>;
    }

    return (
      <div />
    );
  }
}
```

And the test that is failing using both Jest and Enzyme

```
  it('should append the script tag if newUser is true', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<AddScript newUser={true} />);
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    const script = document.body.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    expect(script.src).toEqual('http://www.website.com');
  });
```

With the error message

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined
```

I believe somehow the test is not able to access the if statement, but I'm not sure why that may be the case because surely it checks that conditional before rendering the jsx?

Any pointers? Thank you :)

FYI despite the simplicity of this component I have it as a class component right now because I will likely be adding a lifecycle hook later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shallow render doesn't append the output to the DOM, you need to [mount](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/mount.html) your component if you then want to query `document.body`.

If you simply want to verify though that your component renders `<script>...</script>`, you can still do this with a shallow render. You just need to query the wrapper instead of the DOM

```
it('should append the script tag if newUser is true', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<AddScript newUser={true} />);
  expect(wrapper.html()).toEqual('<script script="http://www.website.com"></script>');
});
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. This did the trick although I had to change to.equal to toEqual or else I received the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'equal' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the script tag in braces:

```
if (newUser) { return ( <script src="http://www.website.com" async={asyncAttribute}> </script>); }
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't fix it :( I still receive the same error. Thanks though

Comment: `return <Component>...</Component>` is valid, you don't need braces.